# Updating jtextarea from another class

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes,

1. Main
2. Sub

In main class, i have a button and jtextarea

In Sub class, i hava a button

when i click on the button in main class, the Sub class runs and shows a button.  When i press on the button in the Sub class, the jtextarea should show the value, "Sample text", but jtextarea is not showing any text.

Sub class code,

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.jTextArea1.setText("Sample text");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't new Main, then you get a different object (that is probably not set to be visible), and nothing will be shown. What you need to do is create a local variable for your Main-object (the one that is showing), as well as a constructor in Sub, like this:

```
private Main main;
public Sub(final Main main) {
    this.main = main();
}
```

then, when you instantiate Sub from Main:

```
final Sub sub = new Sub(this);
```

Then your action in Sub can just say:

```
main.jTextArea1.setText("Sample text")
```

or even better:

```
main.getjTextArea1().setText("Sample text");
```

You should always keep your variables private, and use methods to manipulate them, getters and setters, or something else. You could for instance do it like this:

```
main.displayText("Sample text");
```

This way, Sub does not need to know anything about Mains text area, which is a good thing.

Comment: i have made changes, what change should i have to make, to the code in Sub class, currently i have, public void run() {
                
                new Sub().setVisible(true);
            }

Comment: because, Sub() has becaome Sub(final Main main) now.

Comment: Is the run()-method static? Is it called from Main? If it is, you change it to public void run(final Main main), and call new Sub(main).setVisible(true);

Comment: ok, seems everything is ok, what should i have to do with this code, netbeans automatically implements, @Override
            public void run() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

Comment: That means that it is probably a method that is defined in an interface, that you must implement. But you should not do a new Sub() in this method, since being in it means that you are already in a Sub-object. Change it to this.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0):

As far as the `main` reference is to an object and not the class itself it SHOULD work! However you shall check if the `jTextArea1` is public or private. If private make a `getTextArea()` method return the textarea and call the method (generally that is a better idea). If `sub class` is called from the `main class` and main is a `parent` try to getting the `rootPane` (e.g. sub is a JDialog). Try making a main window externally (in another class) to see how it goes. This solved my problem once in calls between different frames and Dialogs!