# How can I append a JTextArea from a method that doesn't contain the JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, oop, awt, jtextarea

I'm making some test code to practice OOP, and I want to append a JTextArea from the "writeToArea" to the "initialize" method where the JTextArea is defined and initialized. I already tried to directly call the "output" variable, but this returns an "output cannot be resolved" error. I want so that whenever I call the "writeToArea" method in the main class, I'll be able to add lines to the "output" JTextArea in the "initialize" method.

Here's the main class:

```
public class Pangea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UI.initialize();
        UI.writeToArea();
    }
}
```

Here's the initialize class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class UI {

    static void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Initializing GUI.");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Font myFont = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 14);
        JTextField input = new JTextField("");
        JTextArea output = new JTextArea("Initiated Succesfully.");
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setLineWrap(true);
        input.setFont(myFont);
        output.setFont(myFont);
        input.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        output.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        input.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        input.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        output.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        output.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(output);
        frame.setTitle("PANGEA RPG [0.01 ALPHA][WIP]");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("GUI Initialized.");
    }

    static void writeToArea() {
        System.out.println("\"writeToArea\" running.");
        output.append("Hello!");
        System.out.println("\"writeToArea\" finished.");
    }
}
```

I've tried to do something similar to this: [Updating jtextarea from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359059/updating-jtextarea-from-another-class) but it didn't work. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very thankful.

Comment: *"but it didn't work."*  Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error in your code is the lack of OOP design. Making all static is poor design. 
Also swing is event based, so you should append text to the textArea when an event happens. See the example i write for you.

```
public class UI {

   private JPanel panel;
   private JTextArea output;

    public UI(){
       initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        Font myFont = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 14);
        final JTextField input = new JTextField(""); // must be declared final cause you use it in anonymous class, you can make it instance variable if you want to as textArea

        //add an actionListener then when you press enter this will write to textArea
        input.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              @Override             
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                     writeToArea(input.getText());
              }

        });


        output = new JTextArea("Initiated Succesfully",50,100);// let the component determinate its preferred size.
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        output.setLineWrap(true);
        input.setFont(myFont);
        output.setFont(myFont);
        input.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        output.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        input.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        input.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        output.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        output.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(output);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    private void writeToArea(String something) {
        System.out.println("\"writeToArea\" running.");
        output.append(something);
        System.out.println("\"writeToArea\" finished.");
    }


    public JPanel getPanel(){
        return panel;
    }
}
```

And in your client code

```
    public class Pangea {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                   createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });

        }

     /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        System.out.println("Initializing GUI.");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("PANGEA RPG [0.01 ALPHA][WIP]");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new UI().getPanel());


        frame.pack();//sizes the frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("GUI Initialized.");
    }
}
```

Here you have a tutorial with better examples than this [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

I remove your `setSize` and use `pack()`

> The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or
>   above                their preferred sizes. An alternative to pack is
>   to establish a frame size explicitly by  calling setSize or setBounds
>   (which also sets the frame location). In general, using  pack is
>   preferable to calling setSize, since pack leaves the frame layout
>   manager in  charge of the frame size, and layout managers are good at
>   adjusting to platform  dependencies and other factors that affect
>   component size.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the OP's lack of event-driven programming code.

Comment: Tweaked this example code a bit and now it works perfectly! Thanks a ton, I'll be sure to study OOP in detail now. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @Reccy,  `I'll be sure to study OOP in detail` - I already gave you a link to the Swing tutorial two hours before this answer. The tutorial shows you how to do all of this and the structure given there is better than this example (not sure why people post their own code when a tutorial is already available?). Now is as good a time as ever to read the tutorial because there is more than one example there.

Comment: @camickr i just edit OP code, i think is better to show in what he tried to do than simply post tutorials without additional data..

Comment: I think it is better to force someone to think and do some reading. You learn by trying not by using code that someone else wrote for you. By pointing the OP to the tutorial they can start with that working code and then customize it for their particular requirement. Of course the OP accepted this answer because he didn't have to do any work.

Comment: @camickr that's true, but some people like to see how to do well with their example, is easier to understand and see what you are doing bad. If in a few days he ask something simillar then providing solution like mine is a bad idea as you pointed. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: But you only changed a few things (so the bad code is still there) and you were not even consistent in those changes. Why is the text area an instance variable but the text field a final local variable? Both variable are used in the append method so both variables should be instance variables. The OP uses "setPreferredSize()" when he should be using `new JTextArea(text, row, column);`. The OP uses pack() and setSize(), when only pack() should be used. Since no comment was made on this the OP will assume it is ok and do the same in the next program, thus learning bad habits.

Comment: @camickr 1) Instance variable cause use it in another method, the other one not, cause i don't use it, i don't use 2 variables i just pass a string, so that method appends a string not receiveng a `JTextField` it's more generic. The other you are right, i change it :) i like to learn too in this way :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). It will show you how to better structure your code so that you don't use static methods and variables everywhere.

Once you have a panel that has a reference to the text area you can add methods that allow you to update the text area on the panel.