# How can I pass a string from any class to the JTextArea component in the layout class?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jtextarea, getter-setter

I'm using IntelliJ Idea to create a Java application. Using swing, the application's layout contains a component of type `JTextArea` called `textOutput`.

I am trying to pass a string from any of the application's classes back to the layout class that contains the `JTextArea` component so that it can .append and ultimately display this text to the user.  I am currently unable to get the layout class to pick up the string from a utility class containing set/get methods.

Keep in mind that since the layout was created with IntelliJ Idea's layout manager, the component definitions are done in a `.form` file as opposed to in the `.java` file  itself.  Here is what I currently have.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("View");
      frame.setContentPane(new View().tabPane);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

**View.java**

```
public class View {
   public JTabbedPane tabPane;
   private JTextField userText;
   private JTextField passText;
   private JButton loginButton;
   public JTextArea textOutput;

   public View() {
      loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            login(userText.getText(), passText.getText());
         }
      });  
   }

   public void login(String username, String password) {
      URLVisitor visLogin = new URLVisitor();
      visLogin.execute();
   }
}
```

**URLVisitor.java**

```
public class URLVisitor {
   public Logger logger;
   public String text = "";

   public void execute() { 
      logger = new Logger();
      logger.setText("EXECUTE!");

      // some code
   }
}
```

**Logger.java**

```
public class Logger {
   public String text = "";

   public void setText(String text) {
     this.text = text;
   }

   public String getText() {
     return this.text;
   }
}
```

I can successfully set the desired string from any class, but the `View` class is unable to get it.

I tried going from this post's answer:
[How can I append a JTextArea from a method that doesn't contain the JTextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861588/how-can-i-append-a-jtextarea-from-a-method-that-doesnt-contain-the-jtextarea) but the answer uses a user-defined input field as opposed to exporting application-generated text strings as I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Since you want it to occur from "anywhere", you likely need some kind of queue that you can push content onto and then allow the `View` to pool the queue for new content.  This is wandering off into the realms of concurrency, as you will need a background `Thread` of some kind to monitor the queue (and/or use a blocking queue within it) which will need to synch the messages back to the Event Dispatching Thread so they can safely be added to the UI.  A `SwingWoker` might be of some use here...

Comment: Do you know what an instance is?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. I actually have a method in this application that uses a thread.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  So you're saying not to issue the .append from the other classes, but to pool the .appends up and issue the .append each time `View` exits an action that took it into another class?

Comment: @immibis yes why?  If you'd read over the code, you'd already know that as I have instantiated the Logger class.

Comment: Sorry it should have been "poll" and not "pool".  You need to make sure that the `.append` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe

Comment: @dbconfession and is the instance you were writing the value to the same one you were reading it from? (You haven't shown the code you tried to read it, so I can only guess)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, you might be able to use [the Java Logging APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("View");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(new View());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class View extends JPanel {
//    public JTabbedPane tabPane;
//    private JTextField userText;
//    private JTextField passText;
  private JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
  public JTextArea textOutput = new JTextArea();

  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(
      TextAreaLogger.TEST.getClass().getName());

  public View() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    textOutput.setEditable(false);

    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    OutputStream os = new TextAreaOutputStream(textOutput);
    logger.addHandler(new TextAreaHandler(os));


    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //login(userText.getText(), passText.getText());
        login("guest", "guest");
      }
    });

    add(textOutput);
    add(loginButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  public void login(String username, String password) {
    URLVisitor visLogin = new URLVisitor();
    visLogin.execute();
  }
}

class URLVisitor {
  public Logger logger;
  public String text = "";

  public void execute() {
    //logger = new Logger();
    //logger.setText("EXECUTE!");
    logger = Logger.getLogger(
        TextAreaLogger.TEST.getClass().getName());
    logger.info("EXECUTE!");

    // some code
  }
}

enum TextAreaLogger {
  TEST;
}

class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  private final JTextArea textArea;
  public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
    super();
    this.textArea = textArea;
  }
  @Override public void flush() throws IOException {
    super.flush();
    buf.flush();
  }
  @Override public void close() throws IOException {
    super.close();
    buf.close();
  }
  @Override public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    if (b == '\r') {
      return;
    }
    if (b == '\n') {
      final String text = buf.toString("UTF-8");
      buf.reset();
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          textArea.append(text + '\n');
          textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
      });
      return;
    }
    buf.write(b);
  }
}

class TextAreaHandler extends StreamHandler {
  private void configure() {
    setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    try {
      setEncoding("UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      try {
        setEncoding(null);
      } catch (IOException ex2) {
        // doing a setEncoding with null should always work.
        // assert false;
        ex2.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  public TextAreaHandler(OutputStream os) {
    super();
    configure();
    setOutputStream(os);
  }
  @Override public void publish(LogRecord record) {
    super.publish(record);
    flush();
  }
  @Override public void close() {
    flush();
  }
}
```